# Page-specific analytic reports

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-analytics

Does SharePoint 2010 Enterprise provide any analytical reports to show how many times individual pages within a web site were visited? I've looked at the Site Web Analytics reports but that shows aggregate information. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge you can't get to specify a certain page to look at individually other than those in the "Top pages". But auditing could be another way to enable individually tracking of access - simply be aware that a lot of data is stored and make sure you only enable specific events, like "View Only", not all events.