# Reporting on a specific folders

Tags: web-analytics

When referencing Web Analytics all the data is "Top" Rank or "Top" Trend but generally only customizable by date range.

Am I able to customize path as well, for example to determine the exact number of visits a folder got, by who, and between a specified date range?

Possible duplicate to [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73289/page-specific-analytic-reports) unanswered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't choose yourself what to monitor other than the Range specifying the actual period date range.

One alternative is to rely on Auditing capabilities (http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-HA102031737.aspx) which effectively enables tracking multiple event types View-only, Check In/Out, etc.  Running a custom report could enable targeting specific list, list-item, etc.

The main caveat is that a lot of information gets stored so you need to choose which events carefully.